# Convert PHP string with an array statement into a real array

Tags: php, arrays

I got a string var named: `$taxonomy_str`

For example, `echo $taxonomy_str` will display:

```
array('relation' => 'AND', 
  array('taxonomy' => category, 
        'field' => 'id', 
        'terms' => array( 41, 42 ), 
        'operator' => 'IN'), 
  array('taxonomy' => geography,
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 20, 29 ),
        'operator' => 'IN')
)
```

I need a way to convert this string with an array statement into a real array, how can I achieve this using PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: How is this variable being generated? The answer to your question would be `eval()`, but 999 times out of 1000 there is a safer and more elegant alternative to accomplish what you want before you have to resort to `eval()`.

Comment: eval = evil. Just dont do it!

Comment: not even eval can match this beast

Comment: Yes the string is generated and sanitized in a really safe way. Could You provide an example please?

Comment: [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) OR use combinations of [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: @JoséPabloOrozcoMarín If you have access to the source of the string, I recommend that you `json_encode` it and transport it, then use `json_decode` to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat trivial thing to do is simply [`eval`](http://php.net/eval):

```
eval('$foo = ' . $taxonomy_str . ';');
// $foo now contains the outer array
```

(from the comments) maybe better form:

```
$foo = eval('return ' . $taxonomy_str . ';');
```

This literally executes `$taxonomy_str` as if it were source, so any valid PHP provided as input will run. There's a certain level of danger here if you were to say, take `$taxonomy_str` as input from a user.

Comment: Assuming the input string is trustworthy, this is good. If it has any potential to come from the user at all, this is a horrible, horrible idea. I'm not going to up or downvote this, because it really all depends on where the variable comes from. If the variable can be totally trusted, this is a good solution

Comment: Actually, you would need `eval("return $taxonomy_str;")`.

Comment: @NullUserException Too late in the day. I didn't properly read the example. Although I would personally use `$foo = eval("return $taxonomy_str;");`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but it's really not safe if you take your string from the user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`eval`](http://php.net/eval) function. Make sure your string is safe and has no dodgy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval() function. For more information look in PHP official documentations